# Source and save a script from a heredoc

Tags: shell, here-document

I'd like a script to be able to make a copy of itself so it can perform cron tasks, but getting the location of a script from within itself is quite [unreliable in posix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459). A better method would be to make the whole script into a heredoc and source it.

**Is there an elegant POSIX way to do this?**

What I've tried so far, using this example script:

```
#!/bin/sh
FOO='hello world'
echo "$FOO"
cat "$0"
```

## First method

It's written to `/tmp/.script$$` so the script can copy it to a proper place if needed (busybox wasn't compiled with `mktemp`). Running on linux 2.6 without `/dev/fd/` or `/dev/stdin`, but `/proc/self/fd/` is available.

```
#!/bin/sh
trap '{ rm -f "/tmp/.script$$"; exit; }' EXIT INT TERM
tee "/tmp/.script$$" <<'#SCRIPT' | . /proc/self/fd/0
#!/bin/sh
FOO='hello world'
echo "$FOO"
cat "/tmp/.script$$"
#SCRIPT
```

This works but it's sourced in a pipe which means no variables or functions are available on the outside.

## Second method

```
#!/bin/sh
trap '{ rm -f "/tmp/.script$$"; exit; }' EXIT INT TERM
cat > "/tmp/.script$$" <<'#SCRIPT' && . "/tmp/.script$$"
#!/bin/sh
FOO='hello world'
echo "$FOO"
cat "/tmp/.script$$"
#SCRIPT
```

The scope is fixed here but execution relies on the success of writing the script.

## Third method

```
#!/bin/sh
trap '{ rm -f "/tmp/.script$$"; exit; }' EXIT INT TERM
. /proc/self/fd/0 <<EOF
$(tee "/tmp/.script$$" <<': "SCRIPT'
#!/bin/sh
FOO='hello world'
echo "$FOO"
cat "/tmp/.script$$"
: "SCRIPT
)
EOF
#"
```

Functionally this is what I want, but it's quite ugly.

## What doesn't work

```
#!/bin/sh
trap '{ rm -f "/tmp/.script$$"; exit; }' EXIT INT TERM
{ ( tee "/tmp/.script$$" >/proc/$$/fd/0 ) <<'#SCRIPT' & } && . /proc/self/fd/0
#!/bin/sh
FOO='hello world'
echo "$FOO"
cat "/tmp/.script$$"
#SCRIPT
```

This just waits on user input like an interactive shell. I get why that works because stdin isn't closed, but I'm not sure how to open a new file descriptor without linking it to a file (and if I'm going to link it to a file anyway, the second method is cleaner).

Comment: Could you say something more about that initial sentence? What do you mean by "cron task" and why do you think a script needs to be able to copy itself to do this?

Comment: There's a bunch of functions in the script, rather than specifically copying the ones needed to perform cron tasks, it's easier to just copy the whole script.

Comment: @Dabombber Allow me a curiosity: aside the origin of your problem (cronjob etc.), I fail to understand why you don't like your First method: isn't the whole script meant to stay within the Here Document anyway, so that it can copy itself wholly ? ideally there shouldn't be any outer scope to worry about

Comment: The script is mostly just functions, with a minimal `case "$1"` statement at the end to invoke them. I guess it might be a bit too generalised, but it's written so it could be either called or sourced. Eventually I was planning on putting a proper UI in front of it.